# Freezes and reboots that seem to be linked to updates

Tags: kubuntu, kde, freeze

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-78-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV167

My PC will freeze and require a reboot to get it back, and every time, without exception, updates are available when I log in again - the tray icon isn't showing when the freeze happens.

I'd like to try to track this down and get it fixed, but I don't know where to start. I don't know where logs are, or what to look for once I find them. Help?